# How to get the correct window width on orientation change for android devices both tablets and mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, orientation, galaxy

I am trying to calculate the window width on orientation change for android devices using jquery function `$(window).outerWidth(true);`. This calculation gives correct width on orientation change for both `iphone` and `ipad` but not in android. If i initially load the page in landscape mode or portrait mode i am getting the correct width but once i change the orientation after loading the page i am getting the width for portrait mode as was in landscape mode and vice versa. Please suggest what is happening and how can i handle this issue so that i get the correct window width on orientation change in android device

Comment: There is an issue in Android where it sometimes takes a few seconds for the numbers to change. I'm not famililiar with the platform you are using, but in c++, the solution is to poll repeatedly for a few frames after an orientation change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just use the javascript `screen` object. you should be able to get the screen dimensions with :

```
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

Comment: I am using `$(window).outerWidth(true);` as a general for all devices including desktop because i also need to check the browser resize. If i use the above method then i would need to specifically check for android devices. Still will check your answer but why the jquery function is not giving the correct result. What happens for android devices

Comment: I think a more reliable approach may be `screen.availWidth` and `screen.availHeigh` to ignore search bar and browser stuff

Answer (score 7):

I was also stuck in this problem and find the best solution which will work on all the platforms.Below is the code of 'orientationchange' event.

```
function onOrientationChange(event)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
       'Enter you code here';
    },200);
}
```

Hope, it will help you and most of other too.. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

this post seems to have a solution that may be relevant to you:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/orientationchange-event-returns-wrong-values-on-android

Answer (score 1):

```
                            var isMobile = {
                                Android: function () {
                                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
                                },
                                BlackBerry: function () {
                                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
                                },
                                iOS: function () {
                                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
                                },
                                Opera: function () {
                                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
                                },
                                Windows: function () {
                                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
                                },
                                webOS: function () {
                                    return navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i);
                                },
                                any: function () {
                                    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
                                }
                            };


                            var tell_if_mobile;
                            var mobile_tablet;
                            if (isMobile.any()) {
                                tell_if_mobile = true;
                            } else {
                                tell_if_mobile = false;
                                var windowWidth = window.screen.width < window.outerWidth ?
                                                  window.screen.width : window.outerWidth;
                                tell_if_mobile = windowWidth < 800;
                                mobile_tablet = windowWidth >= 500 ? "Tablet/Phablet Device" : "Desktop View (Mobile)";
                            }

                            var mobile_type;
                            mobile_type = isMobile.Android() ? "Android Device" :
                                          isMobile.BlackBerry() ? "Blackberry Device" :
                                          isMobile.iOS() ? "iOS Device" :
                                          isMobile.Opera() ? "Opera Mobile/Mini" :
                                          isMobile.Windows() ? "IEMobile" :
                                          isMobile.webOS() ? "webOS device" :
                                          tell_if_mobile == true ? mobile_tablet :
                                          "Not a mobile device";
alert(mobile_type); //result
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listening to **orientationchange** event , you can listen to window **resize** event , it will make sure that window.innerHeight/outerHeight properties got updated.

Comment: In my case window.innerWidth is not updated after a orientation change triggered resize event

Comment: This is incorrect. The size is still wrong when using
window.addEventListener('resize'

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.innerWidth`, respectively, `window.innerHeight`; It is posible that android doesn't not about outerWidth and Height;

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but it works. [Mobile viewport height after orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452349/mobile-viewport-height-after-orientation-change)

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', () => {
  const tmp = () => {
    this.onResize()
    window.removeEventListener('resize', tmp)
  }
  window.addEventListener('resize', tmp)
})
```