# How to get the correct window width on orientation change for android devices both tablets and phone

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to calculate the window width on orientation change for android devices using jquery function $(window).outerWidth(true);. This calculation gives correct width on orientation change for both iphone and ipad but not in android. If i initially load the page in landscape mode or portrait mode i am getting the correct width but once i change the orientation after loading the page i am getting the width for portrait mode as was in landscape mode and vice versa. Please suggest what is happening and how can i handle this issue so that i get the correct window width on orientation change in android device.

I'm trying to solve with this post [How to get the correct window width on orientation change for android devices both tablets and mobiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215894/how-to-get-the-correct-window-width-on-orientation-change-for-android-devices-bo/34227742?noredirect=1#comment56200217_34227742) , but anything is working for me.

@user850234 any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using the JavaScript window object, try using the angular $window . https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working. I have the same issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'orientationchange' event and the $window service (dont forget to inject $window)

In the angular.run() function, add the following event listener

```
    angular.element($window).bind('orientationchange', function () {
          var width = $window.innerWidth;  
    });
```